# PyCharm: Execute Selection in Console Won't Ignore Leading Whitespace

Tags: pycharm, whitespace

I just updated PyCharm Community to version 2016.3.2 (I don't know what version I was using before the update... embarrassing).

Before updating I used to be able to do the following:

In the editor write

```
def foo():
    x=1
    return 0
```

and then highlight the line containing `x=1` and do "Execute Selection in Console" (shortcut "Alt+ Shift + e"). For highlighted single lines and blocks of code it seemed to strip the correct amount of whitespace so that the console would not see that the code came out of an indented blog in the editor.

Now when I try the same thing the console is unhappy and I receive "IndentationError: unexpected indent".

For obvious reasons this is incredibly annoying :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks to David below who pointed me to the PyCharm resources. This is a known bug as in [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21653) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21991).

Answer (score 0):

For this you would be better going directly to the JetBrains forums and bug tracker tools.      JetBrains develop PyCharm and if there is a bug they will know the answer.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY can be used to track existing and known bugs.

The [PyCharm Forums](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200379535-PyCharm) can be used to ask these sort of questions as well.

Comment: Thank you David, I will definitely do that.

Comment: As per the Stack Overflow guidelines : If you like a response Don't respond with "thanks" ,   give it an up vote.